# Using Perl Win7 to write a file for Linux and having only Linux line endings

Tags: linux, perl, file, eol

This Perl script is **running on Win7**, modifying a Clearcase config spec that will be **read on a Linux** machine.  Clearcase is very fussy about its line endings, they must be precisely and only \n (0x0A) however try as I may I cannot get Perl to spit out only \n endings, they usually come out \r\n (0x0D 0x0A)

Here's the Perl snippet, running over an array of config spec elements and converting `element /somevob/...` bits into `element /vobs/somevob/...` and printing to a file handle.

```
        $fh = new FileHandle;
    foreach my $line (@cs_array)
        {
        $line =~ s/([element|load])(\s+\/)(.+)/$1$2vobs\/$3/g; 
        $line =~ s/[\r\n]/\n/g;  # tried many things here
        $fh->print($line);
        }
    $fh->close();
```

Sometimes the elements in the array are multi-line and separated by \n

```
element /vob1/path\nelement\n/vob2/path\nload /vob1/path\n element\n
/vob3/path 
load /vob3/path
```

When I look into the file written on Win7 in a binary viewer there is always a 0x0D 0x0A newline sequence which Clearcase on Linux complains about.  This appears to come from the print.

Any suggestions?  I thought this would be a 10 minute job...

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying `\x0A` instead of `\n`? IIRC, the `\n` is a logical line ending.

Comment: @amon as far as I've been able to tell, that's not true in Perl. `\r` is `\x0d`, `\n` is `\x0a`, and it's just IO layers that translate between `\r\n` and `\n` at the boundaries. If anyone can prove me wrong, I'd like to see it.

Comment: @hobbs That makes sense (it has been some time since I've written something for Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$fh->binmode;
```

Otherwise you're probably in text mode, and for Windows this means that `\n` is translated to `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You are running afoul of the `:crlf` IO Layer that is the default for Perl on Windows.
You can use `binmode` after the fact to remove this layer, or you can open the filehandle with `:raw` (the default layer for *nix) or some other appropriate IO Layer in the 1st place.

Sample:

```
$fh = FileHandle->new($FileName, '>:raw')
```

Check `perldoc open` for more details on IO Layers.